# Is an Aluminium or Plastic Paint Container Better for Air Painting?

Tags: paint, tools

I'm interested in buying an air paint gun (Probably from Harbor Freight), and I'm curious as to whether there are any advantages or disadvantages to using an aluminium paint container in a gravity fed paint gun, or should I use a plastic one? I would think that the possibility of a plastic container would be nice, but sticking with an aluminium one might be cheaper and more environmentally friendly, and maybe a plastic one would be easier to clean? I'm not sure. Is there a noticeable trade off between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I use a plastic cup and haven't had any problems, despite the fact that I shoot a 2-part LPU (what Boeing paints the Dreamliner with) and the solvent for the stuff is so caustic it's a *paint stripper* for latex and some aklyds. I expected it would have wrecked the cup, but it didn't.

I am partial to a [very well rated](http://amzn.to/2qAOTQ9) touch up gun I found on Amazon.  Despite being cheap Cheese, it's a bulletproof little thing and about $35.